# How can I open a Fragment under the open NavigationDrawer with defining the Drawer in a separate fragment?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android-framelayout

My app opens the NavigationDrawer at start. 
When the user clicks on any item in it a Fragment is being replaced.

For every item in my navigation drawer I have a separate Fragment. 
BUT when the user does not choose any of the options in the NavigationDrawer and CLOSES it,
the main activit layout is being shown.

I want one of my own fragments to be brought up when the user closes the side menu. (navigation drawer)
But I get a NPE when I try to change

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_fragment);
```

(Because it cannot find navigation_drawer since it is defined in activity_main)

I don't like to put my NavigationDrawer in one of my fragments, neither do I like to copy my fragment elements to my main.xml (it will be a messy design :( ).
 What am I supposed to do?
How am I supposed to open my desired fragment underneath the NavigationDrawer??

here is my onCreate in MainActivity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    mTitle = getTitle();
}
```

here is my activity_main.xml

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
```

```
<!--
     As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions.
-->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<!--
     android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
     this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
     languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
     If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
     android:layout_gravity="left" instead.
-->
<!--
     The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
     the container.
-->

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
    android:name="com.khoonat.khoonat.FragmentNavigationDrawer"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
```

Is this a bad solution? 
please note that I'm kind of a beginner :)

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, FragmentSearchPropertyListing.newInstance(0)).commit();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (FragmentNavigationDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
    mTitle = getTitle();
}
```

The red arrow shows what I mean by under the navigation drawer.
[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Did you follow the tutorial at http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html?

Comment: it's not clear what you're trying to do. *I want one of my own fragments to be brought up when the user closes the side menu.* - what exactly do you understand by brought up?

Comment: I mean under the Drawer, instead of an empty page, i want a custom fragment. I have used ADT's navigation drawer project.

Comment: @Tina If you used the ADT template, the first `Fragment` should be loading automatically. Does it show "1" in the top-left corner?